# Off Topic Migration to Security Stackexchange

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic

It is not often, but it can occur that a post belong to Security Stackexchange.

What about adding it to the migration list ?

[image]

It would fit the empty space !

Some examples this week:

- [Why are some big corporations still worried about cloud security?](https://serverfault.com/questions/739215/why-are-some-big-corporations-still-worried-about-cloud-security)
- [Q: Strange web traffic - Is this an attack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/739442/q-strange-web-traffic-is-this-an-attack)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/738880/ssh-intrusion-suspected-logwatch-report-versus-ssh-log-file-entries
- https://serverfault.com/questions/739028/should-i-really-treat-memory-leaks-like-classical-bandwith-dos

Comment: If it's not often, then it's not needed.

Comment: None of those are off topic for SF. The first and last are a bit broad/opinion-based so don't really have a home on SE, so there really isn't a need to migrate them. **Please, also, stop leaving comments about $elsewhere being better.** That's not necessarily the case, and people saying the same on SO are a real source of irritation here.

Answer (score 10):

We can't add more targets to the migration list (it's an arbitrary hard limit set by the SE staff).

The sites currently on the list (SO, SU, U&L, DBA) are much more important.

Some stats for migration in the last 90 days:

```
SU:  152
U&L:  79
SO:   37
DBA:  18
SEC:   4
```

When you think it's really necessary to migrate, raise a flag (the mod might disagree though and reject the flag).

Comment: In fact stats aren't really accurate, some posts are not migrated.

Comment: @Froggiz What do you want to say with this? The reject rates are ~10%, this don't change this statistic.

Comment: That some post which should be migrated are in status closed or even not touched, so they are not in statistics. But yes it is still less than other sites